# pandas groupby aggregate keep equal values

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to build an aggregator which simply returns a value if it is equal to all other values in the variable and NaN if it isn't.

It is ment to keep meta information while aggregating sensory data.

I get a strange key error...

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict({'v1' : [1,1,1,2,2,2],
                             'v2' : [1,2,3,4,5,6],
                             'v3' : [1,1,1,2,3,2],
                             'v4' : [2,2,2,3,3,3]})
def keep_equal(x):
    if (x == x[0]).all(): return x[0]
    else: return np.NaN

df =  df.groupby(df["v1"], as_index=False, observed =True).agg(keep_equal)
```

expected output would be:

```
     v1   v2  v3  v4
 0   1  NaN   1   2
 1   2  NaN   NaN 3
```

But I get a key error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "pandas\_libs\index.pyx", line 131, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc

  File "pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 998, in pandas._libs.hashtable.Int64HashTable.get_item

KeyError: 0
```

Comment: Tryin using `iloc` ie change the `if` line to `if (x == x.iloc[0]).all(): return x.iloc[0]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to check for the location with `iloc`

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict({'v1' : [1,1,1,2,2,2],
                             'v2' : [1,2,3,4,5,6],
                             'v3' : [1,1,1,2,3,2],
                             'v4' : [2,2,2,3,3,3]})
def keep_equal(x):
    if (x == x.iloc[0]).all(): return x.iloc[0]
    else: return np.NaN

df =  df.groupby(df["v1"], as_index=False, observed =True).agg(keep_equal)
print(df)
>>
   v1  v2   v3  v4
0   1 NaN  1.0   2
1   2 NaN  NaN   3
```

Answer (score 1):

If performance is important better is use [`Series.iat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.iat.html) for select first value of `Series` here:

```
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict({'v1' : [1,1,1,2,2,2],
                             'v2' : [1,2,3,4,5,6],
                             'v3' : [1,1,1,2,3,2],
                             'v4' : [2,2,2,3,3,3]})
def keep_equal(x):
    if (x == x.iat[0]).all(): 
        return x.iat[0]
    else: 
        return np.NaN
```

Or working with `1d` numpy arrays:

```
def keep_equal(x):
    if (x == x.values[0]).all(): 
        return x.values[0]
    else: 
        return np.NaN

df =  df.groupby(df["v1"], as_index=False).agg(keep_equal)
print (df)
   v1  v2   v3  v4
0   1 NaN  1.0   2
1   2 NaN  NaN   3
```